# Не выводится jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, heroku, controller

Подключил пустой проект Spring boot к Heroku. У меня получилось выводить информацию текстом без jsp. Когда пытаюсь вывести jsp, выводится просто имя jsp файла строкой.

Controller

```
package goa.demo;

import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    Controller(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
        List users = (List) usersRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "index";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public String onExpeption() {
        return "Wrong page number";
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой шаблонизатор используется?

Answer (score 0):

Замените `@RestController` на `@Controller`. 
`@RestController` добавляет `@ResponseBody` к каждому методу. Также должен быть сконфигурирован ViewResolver. Например, так

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```